# How to find xpath of hard rubber ball in below HTML code?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to find xpath of hard rubber ball in below HTML code from the image ?

[Click to view HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZFC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //[@class='sport-list']//span[text()='hard rubber ball']

Or directly use

> //span[text()='hard rubber ball']

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your sample code, I think that this selenium locator would work for the checkbox:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selected_sport[]']"));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!